# Typing static methods returning class instance

Tags: python, types, static-methods, type-hinting

How can I type a static method that returns an instance object?

```
import typing

class foo(object):

  @staticmethod
  def getOne() -> foo:
    return FooRegister().get()
```

`FooRegister` contains all the instances of `foo`. If however I type it as shown, python complains since `foo` hasn't been defined yet.

What's the correct way to type this?

Comment: Well, technically your return value's type is `type` or a subclass thereof if you are returning class objects.

Comment: Using a string is very common: `def getOne() -> 'foo':`. That's interpreted as ["forward referencing"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) with typehints.

Comment: @MSeifert that works. Thanks. Apologies for the duplicate.